# state inside function not updating

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know why the state inside a function isn't updating and sometimes the btnRef in Ss file always null so the addEventListener not working

```
//App.tsx

import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Ss from "./Ss";

export default function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef<any>(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Ss btnRef={btnRef.current} />
      <div ref={btnRef}>click</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//Ss.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Ss({ btnRef }: { btnRef?: Element }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  function asd() {
    console.log("current:", current);
    setCurrent((prev) => prev + 1);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    btnRef?.addEventListener("click", asd);
  }, [btnRef]);

  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: this is actually pretty rare case of react i m seeing right now.. adding clickEvent listener to ref inside the children..

Comment: nope, this case is used when you want make component with a custom button

Comment: i believe you can use React.forwarfRef to pass the ref from parent to children component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btnRef.current` in `<Ss btnRef={btnRef.current} />` will be null because you are passing it to **Ss** before the `div` is even mounted on the DOM.

```
<Ss btnRef={btnRef.current} />
<div ref={btnRef}>click</div>
```

Since the **App** is not re-rendered after that , `btnRef` prop in **Ss** is still null.

**Solution:**

Instead of passing `btnRef.current` to **Ss** , pass the `btnRef` directly `current` property in `btnRef` will be updated when div is mounted.

```
<Ss btnRef={btnRef} />
<div ref={btnRef}>click</div>
```

**Ss.tsx**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = btnRef.current;
    el.addEventListener("click", asd);
    return () => el.removeEventListener("click", asd);
  }, [btnRef, current]);
```

Add the `current` counter state to useEffect deps if you want `console.log("current:", current);` to log the correct state value and don't forget to cleanup the `click` listener.

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cherry-8s9uj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: do you have any sugestion to handle this case ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution.